# SAML identity provider implementation in node.js?

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0, passport-saml

**Is there is any library for making saml identity provider in node.js.**

I am checking saml implementation in node.js they all say service provider code and identity provider as oauth or openlogin url.

Some library i found for service provider are **passport-saml** , **saml2-js**.

> Can you tell is there is implementation of saml identity provider in node.js?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097666/handle-the-identity-provider-side-of-saml-using-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle the Identity provider side of SAML using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097666/handle-the-identity-provider-side-of-saml-using-node-js)