# Handle the Identity provider side of SAML using Node.js

Tags: node.js, saml, federated-identity, idp, passport-saml

I need to implement an Identity provider service (using node.js) that should be able to.

- Get, validate and parse (using private key and cretificate) the authentication request from SP [example](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php)
- If everything is valid, respond with a signed XML response [example](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php)

  Is there a tool in node.js that can handle the IdP side of SAML protocol. i'm familiar with [samlify](https://samlify.js.org/#/), [saml2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js), [passport-saml](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/), and all of them seem to handle the Service provider side of the protocol.

---

If the packages mentioned here can serve to my needs, could you specify how exactly they handle this.
Any other directions and/or hints may be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement the identity provider service?

Comment: hi @MykytaManuilenko Actually we opted out for a different solution so Identity Provider for SAML was not implemented

Answer (score 6):

This is what my research say about this modules .

Passport-saml - Provider service provider only

Saml2-js -           Provide service provider

Samlify -            Idp in experimental phase , You can check idp implementation here. https://github.com/tngan/samlify/blob/f2b6a2f8c36dc0ff887d0442c48cd0f2c0a4a778/examples

Node-samlp -   IDP which provide saml assertion but user authorization we need to do our own

Saml-idp -          It says IDP we can create but again it refer to online IDP

Comment: That is to say there's nothing like simplesamlPhp for node

Comment: Samlify can be cansidered for this case. I have used for IDP intiated SSO.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [samlify](https://samlify.js.org/) to make my existing node js application as identity provider to third party service provider.

It has many configuration options. Intially it took time to successfully implement.